# How to get the AssemblyVersion of a .Net file in Linux

Tags: .net, linux, mono, assemblyinfo

Is there any way to obtain the AssemblyVersion of a .Net executable in Linux without using mono?  What I am trying to have is a script or command that will let me obtain the AssemblyVersion on Linux boxes.  I tried:

```
#strings file.exe | grep AssemblyVersion
```

but it only the string and not the number.  Also checked with:

```
#file file.exe
```

but only got general information.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 30):

Try to match version numbers that span a whole line:

```
$ strings file.exe | egrep '^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$'
```

In my (few) tests, the `AssemblyVersion` of the binary was always the last result.

Comment: I tested it but none of the numbers I am getting are the AssemblyVersion.  In fact, I don't see the AssemblyVerson anywhere in the strings output.

Comment: Use `-el` on the strings command to interpret the strings as unicode.

Answer (score 14):

As recommended by [Jb Evain](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-list/2008-December/040558.html) you can use the [Mono Disassembler](http://www.mono-project.com/Dis/Assembling_CIL_Code).

```
monodis --assembly file.exe | grep Version
```

Comment: For compatibility with a wider sample of assemblies, use `ikdasm -assembly` (also distributed with Mono) instead of `monodis --assembly`.

Answer (score 11):

Another option is to use [`exiftool`](https://iffybooks.net/wp-content/uploads/zines/Iffy_Books_Exiftool_print.pdf), as in:

```
$ exiftool -AssemblyVersion -ProductVersion ./System.Private.CoreLib.dll
Assembly Version                : 7.0.0.0
Product Version                 : 7.0.4+0a396acafe9a7d46bce11f4338dbb3dd0d99b1b4
```

Comment: It's absurd and ridiculous but exiftool can actually read the dotnet assembly info! It reads other properties as well. And `exiftool ./System.Private.CoreLib.dll` is much simpler than using monodis. Not to speak of microsofts own dotnet-ildasm. Cudos @vulcan-raven and to dthe devs of exiftool.

Answer (score 5):

The `ikdasm` tool that is also [distributed with Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/) is more robust than `monodis`, which unfortunately crashes with the message "Segmentation fault: 11" on many DLL files. The maintainers explicitly recommend the use of `ikdasm` rather than `monodis`: https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/8900#issuecomment-428392112

Usage example (with an assembly that `monodis` currently cannot handle):

```
ikdasm -assembly System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll | grep Version:
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a *really* old question and just about everything has changed, but as of dotnet 2.1 (so you can `dotnet tool install`) you can install `dotnet-ildasm`:

```
dotnet tool install --tool-path . dotnet-ildasm
```

Then you can use this function:

```
function dll_version {
  local dll="$1"
  local version_line
  local version

  version_line="$(./dotnet-ildasm "$dll" | grep AssemblyFileVersionAttribute)"
  # Uses SerString format:
  #   01 00 is Prolog
  #   SZARRAY for NumElem
  #   version chars for Elem
  #   00 00 for NamedArgs
  # See:
  #   https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf#%5B%7B%22num%22%3A2917%2C%22gen%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22XYZ%22%7D%2C87%2C321%2C0%5D
  [[ $version_line =~ \(\ 01\ 00\ [0123456789aAbBcCdDeEfF][0123456789aAbBcCdDeEfF]\ (.*)\ 00\ 00\ \)$ ]]
  dotcount=0
  for i in ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; do
    if [[ $i =~ ^2[eE]$ ]]; then
      (( dotcount++ ))
    fi
    if (( dotcount == 3 )); then
      break
    fi
    echo -n -e "\u$i"
  done
}
```

Answer (score 3):

to return just the vesion using monodis, use this code

```
monodis --assembly LDAPService.dll | grep Version | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'
```

Installation packages: https://command-not-found.com/monodis

For example in ubuntu

```
apt-get install mono-utils
```