# mcs giving me warning CS1701?

Tags: .net, compiler-errors, mono, json.net

I have a project written in C# targetting .NET version 4.6.1 on Windows that I'm also compiling with mcs on mono 4.2.1 on Debian Jessie.

The command I use to compile the program is

```
mcs -define:LINUX -langversion:experimental -platform:x64 -recurse:'*.cs' -optimize+ -r:$DLLS -out:$CURRENTDIR/program.exe
```

where `$DLLS` is a list of DLLs in `$CURRENTDIR`.

What bothers me is that the compiler throws the following warning. The program works as expected, but I'm clueless as to **why this warning appears and how I can potentially fix it.**

```
warning CS1701: Assuming assembly reference `Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' matches assembly `Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. You may need to supply runtime policy
Compilation succeeded - 1 warning(s)
```

All lines referencing Newtonsoft.Json in the project

```
$ grep -rh Newtonsoft .
<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.2\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.2" targetFramework="net461" />
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

The referenced DLL is version 8.0.0.0 according to these commands recommended in [How to get the AssemblyVersion of a .Net file in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3946368/1780502) and I've tried getting the latest version via NuGet on both Windows (via Visual Studio 2015) and Linux via [nuget.exe](https://dist.nuget.org/index.html) (v3.3.0).

```
$ monodis --assembly Newtonsoft.Json.dll | grep Version
Version:       8.0.0.0
$ strings Newtonsoft.Json.dll | egrep '^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$'
8.0.2.19309
```

The project originally used Newtonsoft.Json v7, but was updated to 8.0.2 before I ever compiled it under Linux.

Comment: Have the exact same problem.  Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.2 (Stable 4.2.2.30/996df3c), Monodevelop 5.1, Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Same problem when adding the Newtonsoft.Json 8.0.2 package to the C# project in Visual Studio 2015: Include contains full assembly name for version 8.0.0 and HintPath refers correct version 8.0.0. This leads to runtime issue when 8.0.0 is not found.